# Find the order of $\tau^{100}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $\tau= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13\\2&4&5&8&7&12&9&1&11&10&13&6&3\end{array} \right)$

> I need to find the order of $\tau^{100}$

**I know that:**

$\tau=(1, 2 ,4 ,8),(3 ,5 ,7 ,9 ,11 ,13),(6,12),(10)$

> Now what should I do? any hints please?

Comment: Hint: Find the orders of each of those cycles and take the lcm. That is the order of $\tau$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that the order of a permutation is the $\mathrm{lcm}$ of the lengths of the cycles in its cycle decomposition. For example, if
$$\sigma=\underbrace{(\cdots\cdots)}_{\text{length 4}}\underbrace{(\cdots\cdots\cdots)}_{\text{length 7}}\underbrace{(\cdots\cdots)}_{\text{length 6}}$$
then $\mathrm{ord}(\sigma)=\mathrm{lcm}(4,7,6)=84$.
Then, prove that in any group $G$, if $g\in G$ has finite order then
$$\mathrm{ord}(g^k)=\frac{\mathrm{ord}(g)}{\gcd(\mathrm{ord}(g),k)}.$$